# Number each line (in the middle) of a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file like this:

```
|DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
|DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
|DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
|DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
```

And I have the following code to number each line:

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as readFile:
    content = readFile.read()
    contentList = content.split("\n")
    count = 0

    for content in contentList:
        count += 1
        print(f"[{count}]: {content}")
```

Now, the problem is, the result is like this:

```
[1]: |DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
[2]: |DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
[3]: |DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
[4]: |DeviceImage|number|DeviceName
```

How can I replace the number in each line in the text file? Basically, All I want is to number each line where the number is, Line this:

```
|DeviceImage|1|DeviceName
|DeviceImage|2|DeviceName
|DeviceImage|3|DeviceName
|DeviceImage|4|DeviceName
```

Comment: Is it actually the word "number"? Is it always 3 columns separated by "|" ?

Comment: You're using the word "number" too much. Please [edit] your question and post example input (with actual values), your desired output, and the actual output.

Comment: please refresh, I added the target output that I need\

Comment: Are the numbers in the second field always in order like that, or can they be random. Additionally, does `count` need to equal the second field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to print your target output you can do this,

```
for content in contentList:
    count += 1
    print(f"[{count}]: {content.replace('number', str(count))}")
```

For actually modifying the file, open it in 'r+' mode and, with the same statement you can write it in the file. This should work,

```
with open("test.txt", 'r+') as readFile:
    content = readFile.read()
    contentList = content.split("\n")
    count = 0
    readFile.seek(0)
    readFile.truncate()
    for content in contentList:
        count += 1
        readFile.write(content.replace('number', str(count)))
        readFile.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```py
with open("test.txt", 'r') as readFile:
    content = readFile.read()
    contentList = content.split("\n")
    count = 0

    for content in contentList:
        count += 1
        splt = content.split("|")
        splt[2] = count
        print("|".join(splt))
```

Split by '|' and just parse out the middle string to replace with count